# ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "Test"

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to learn Telethon. I wanted to get all the messages from a 'Test' group I created

```
import os
import sys
import time

from telethon import TelegramClient, events, utils,sync
from telethon.tl.types import Chat


api_id = **
api_hash = '**'
proxy = None 
phone_number='*****'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
channel_username = 'Test' //<==Group Name
for message in client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=10):
    print(message.message)
```

But I always get this error

```
<module>
    for message in client.get_messages(channel_username, limit=10):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified     
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete   
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 574, in get_messages
    return await it.collect()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 113, in collect
    async for message in self:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 58, in __anext__
    if await self._init(**self.kwargs):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 26, in _init
    self.entity = await self.client.get_input_entity(entity)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 432, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 569, in _get_entity_from_string
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "Test"
```

Can someone please help me in solving this issue

Comment: `channel_username` has to be the channel username or channel ID, and not channel name.

Comment: @PrashantSengar Ohk thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should enter an entity(id or ....) to get messages

E.G:

```
channel_username = "@telegram"
```

Comment: I have the ID of the group how do I get the entity?